# About pointers and arrays

Tags: c++, c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char *syllable[26] = {"a","bub","cash","dud","e","fud","gug","hash","i","jay",
    "kuck","lul","mum","nun","o","pub","quack","rug","sus",
    "tut","u","vuv","wack","xux","yuck","zug"};

void Tutnese(char *word, char *newword);
char *letter;


void Tutnese(char *word, char *newword)
{

    //clrscr();
    for(*letter = 'A'; *letter <= 'Z'; *letter++)
    {
        letter=syllable;
        printf("%c\n",&letter);
    }
}
```

Tutnese is an English language game primarily used by children who use it to converse in 
(perceived) privacy from adults (or vice versa)

I am trying to let A="A" B="bub" c="cash" and so on. 
I am expecting a result like this.

“computer.” becomes “cashomumpubututerug.” 
- “Stony” become “Sustutonunyuck”

but i just start learning c, and i have no idea how to use pointer. I've been keep getting error like assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

Comment: I highly recommend going through the pointers section in your book or finding some tutorials. There are so many problems with this code.

Comment: The relationship between arrays and pointers in C can be confusion. Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) has the best explanation I've seen.

Comment: `s/confusion/confusing/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Code

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *syllable[26] = {"a","bub","cash","dud","e","fud","gug","hash","i","jay",
    "kuck","lul","mum","nun","o","pub","quack","rug","sus",
    "tut","u","vuv","wack","xux","yuck","zug"};

void Tutnese(char *word, char *newword, size_t new_size);

void Tutnese(char *word, char *newword, size_t new_size)
{
    char *end = newword + new_size;
    char c;
    while ((c = *word++) != '\0')
    {
        if (!isalpha(c))
            *newword++ = c;
        else
        {
            char *tut = syllable[tolower(c) - 'a'];
            ptrdiff_t len = strlen(tut);
            if (end - newword <= len)
                break;
            memcpy(newword, tut, len + 1);
            newword += len;
        }
    }
    *newword = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
    char i_data[1024];
    char o_data[4096];

    while (fgets(i_data, sizeof(i_data), stdin) != 0)
    {
        Tutnese(i_data, o_data, sizeof(o_data));
        printf("I: %sO: %s", i_data, o_data);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

#### Output

```
I: computer
O: cashomumpubututerug
I: how do you tell mum that she cannot understand us?
O: hashowack dudo yuckou tutelullul mumumum tuthashatut sushashe cashanunnunotut ununduderugsustutanundud usus?
I: The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
O: tuthashe quackuicashkuck bubrugowacknun fudoxux jayumumpubedud ovuverug tuthashe lulazugyuck dudogug.
```

Answer (score 1):

`char *letter;`
This statement declares a variable named `letter`, same way as any other statement like `char ch;` will do.

Now, what's the difference then!!

Well the difference (and similarity) is:

1. `char ch;` declares a `char` variable, i.e. a memory block of size 1 byte is allocated (statically), which you can refer to using `ch`.
2. `char *letter;` on the other hand declares a `char pointer` i.e. a memory size of 2 or 4 or 8 bytes (depending on compiler) will be allocated (again statically) to store **address** of a **`char` variable**.

Now when you use `*letter` as lvalue (on Left Hand Side) as you do in `for` loop, this means you are trying to write to the memory address stored in `letter`. In your case you never stored any address in `letter`, to do so you can use `letter = &ch;` where `ch` is some `char` variable.

That was all the lecture!!

Now my suggestion for your program:

1. You don't need to use `letter` pointer for the loop, a simple `char i` variable will be fine.
2. To re-form the string as you plan to, you can simply use the characters of the original string as indices to form new string. Declare a empty string of some large length, then keep concatenating the `syllable[orig_string[i] - 'A']`, inside a `for` loop till the end of `orig_string`. Assumption is `orig_string` contains all **uppercase** alphabets
3. Finally, Correct your `printf` syntax.

Do read about **pointers in C** from a good source, as they will never leave you, and will give you all sorts of nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

Lets forget about pointers and break down the problem.
You're given a word `word` and you want to create `newword` based on your mapping.

First, you need to figure out how big `newword` is.
To do that, iterate through the characters in `word` and add the string lengths of the mappings (call it `N`)
Once you've done that, you know you can allocate N+1 bytes (strings are null terminated in C) for `newword` (via `malloc`).
Then, you iterate through the characters again and just append to `newword`

Let me give you a few hints:
To iterate through a string (lets call it `word`), the C code would look like:

```
unsigned int wordlen = strlen(word);
for(unsigned int index = 0; index < wordlen; index++)
    printf("Character at %u is %c", index, word[index]);
```

Your for loop is quite messed up. Do look up a few tutorials on pointers and string manipulation in C.